# can i put an array of structs inside an array of structs?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, dynamic, typedef

im trying to make a project where i can access multiple companies, and inside of each company there can be multiple coments and ratings, and this is what i came up with:

```
#define COMPANY_INITIAL_SIZE 20
#define SEARCHES_INITIAL_SIZE 20

#define TEXT_MAX_SIZE 200
#define NAME_MAX_SIZE 50
#define EMAIL_MAX_SIZE 50
#define TITLE_MAX_SIZE 50
#define ADDRESS_MAX_SIZE 70
#define LOCATION_MAX_SIZE 70
#define CATEGORY_MAX_SIZE 30

#define NIF_MIN_SIZE 100000000
#define NIF_MAX_SIZE 999999999

    enum category {
        microCompany = 1, pmeCompany, macroCompany
    };

    enum state {
        inactive, active
    };

    enum searchCamp {
        nif, businessArea, nameLocation
    };
    
    enum comentState {
        hidden,visible
    };

    typedef struct {
        char title[TITLE_MAX_SIZE];
        char text[TEXT_MAX_SIZE];
        char userName[NAME_MAX_SIZE];
        char userEmail[EMAIL_MAX_SIZE];
        enum comentState states;
    } Coment;

    typedef struct {
        int nota;
        char userName[NAME_MAX_SIZE];
        char userEmail[EMAIL_MAX_SIZE];
    } Rating;

    typedef struct {
        int Nif;
        char name[NAME_MAX_SIZE];
        enum category categories;
        int businessAreaCode;
        enum state states;
        char address[ADDRESS_MAX_SIZE];
        char location[LOCATION_MAX_SIZE];
        int postalCode;
        int comentCounter,comentSize;
        Coment coments;
        int ratingCounter,ratingSize;
        Rating ratings;
    } Company;

    typedef struct {
        int counter, size;
        Company *companies;
    } Companies;
```

but after trying to insert coments in the companies it gives me this error:
subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector.

```
void insertComent(Companies *companies) {
    int company, nif;
    char title[TITLE_MAX_SIZE], text[TEXT_MAX_SIZE], name[NAME_MAX_SIZE], email[EMAIL_MAX_SIZE];

    nif = getInt(NIF_MIN_SIZE, NIF_MAX_SIZE, "\nNIF [9 digits]: ");

    company = verifyIfCompanyExists(*companies, nif);
    if (company != -1) {

        readString(title, TITLE_MAX_SIZE, "\nTitle: ");

        strcpy(companies->companies[company].coments[companies->companies[company].comentCounter].title, title); //<- this is the line that gives the error.

        readString(text, TEXT_MAX_SIZE, "\nTitle: ");
        strcpy(companies->companies->coments.text, text);
        readString(name, NAME_MAX_SIZE, "\nUserName: ");
        strcpy(companies->companies->coments.userName, name);
        readString(email, EMAIL_MAX_SIZE, "\nEmail: ");
        strcpy(companies->companies->coments.userEmail, email);


    }
}
```

i tried searching if what i was doing was possible but nothing that i got told me anything.

Comment: `Coment coments;` is **not** an array of comments! Maybe you want `Coment coments[256];` or similar. Or `Coment *coments;` and then do dynamic allocation to avoid having a fixed number of comments.

Comment: For the title: Yes, you can make a struct that contains an array of another struct and then you can make an array of the first struct. No problem.

Comment: Sorry, there's not enough code here to make a reproducible example.  `verifyIfCompanyExists()` isn't defined.  But like user  Support Ukraine told, you can certainly make an array of structs inside an array of structs.  Note [this godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/deGv79xnG) and that the compiler does not complain about any of the structure designs and won't, unless you use them improperly.

Comment: Regarding the title: You cannot add anything to an array of structs except more elements in that array. But you can add another array of structs to the structs you hold in your array.